# Hyper-V VM moving went wrong

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualization, hyper-v

I had a little project to move our DHCP server from an old host to a new one. It looked dead simple.. but after I moved it manually ( copying vhd to new host and then configuring VM there) the Guest on the new host cannot acces internet. I have been trying to figure it out as other VM-s can access it with the same virtual switch. I have set the IP config as it was before and the Guest cannot ping the default gateway but it can communicate on our domain network.

The Guest is a windows2008r2 being version 3.0 VM but on the new Host it is 5.0 and still gen 1.
The gateway has no problems as my laptop and any other domain joined pc can ping it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats the DNS server? can you ping the DNS from the new guest?

Comment: Primary dns server is good. But the secondary is gateway(modem).

Comment: I hope you don't mean that you have AD domain clients using your modem for DNS. If you do, you've got more wrong than just this VM. As for this VM, did you create a new VM on the host and configure it to use the VHD for this VM?

Comment: It is not my setup :) our AD/DC is the DNS too.. and the modem has a forwarding to an external dns provided by our peivate ISP. Yes i created a new VM as the import failed all the time. The problem is that it is a crucial part of our network as it is our VPN too and oue japanese managers are knocking on our shoulders :)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:
- Have you installed the latest version of the integration components in the guest OS?
- You have a new NIC - have you configured IPv4 and ensured that DHCP is approved (approve it again)?
- Are the phsyical NIC(s) that the vSwitch connected to 1 GbE? If so, is VMQ disabled on the physical NICs? It needs to be because of bad implementations by the OEMs.

Comment: Yes, I have already upgraded the intergration services and configured IPv4and VMQ was disabled too. That is why it confuses me.
The intereseting part is that I tried to export it out and import on the new host and the import failed all the time without a reason.